# Passing tap action from one view to another

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two UIViews A and B. Both of these views are placed one on another. Suppose View A is placed above B. So when I tap on View A it is consuming all tap actions. But I dont want that action to be consumed till View A only. I want to get actions on View B where it was tapped.

All my view has `userInteractionEnabled = true`

```
class PassthroughView : UIView {
  override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? 
  {
    let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    return view == self ? nil : view
  }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        print("Tap Called")
        return false
    }
}
```

I tried these codes after see some solutions but doesnt seems to be working.

Also View A has swipe gesture to work.

```
 _V_i_e_w_B___
|   ____
|  |View A
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|__|__
   |_____
```

Comment: If you have swipe gesture in view A, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

In UIView subclass override hitTest method only

```
class PassthroughView : UIView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        return view == self ? nil : view
    }
}
```

And create view A with the subclass and another view B with UIView class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let b = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        b.backgroundColor = .gray
        b.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(b)

        let a = PassthroughView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 275, height: 275))
        a.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        a.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(a)       
    }
}
```

Comment: But then will I be able to use swipe gesture on `PassthroughView`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever View A is placed above View B change the userInteractionEnabled to false for View A and your tap will be passed to View B.